# map point filtering by distance

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps

i want to filter my gps points (reduce the number of points shown) by calculating the distance between the points and if the distance is less than 300 meters then do not add the next point to the map.

Here is my current javascript to create the markers and polylines

```
var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            jQuery("#gMap").gmap3({ action: 'clear' });
            jQuery(".marker").remove();
            var counts = 0;

            jQuery.each(json, function(i, item) {
                var polyArray=[];
                var name = item.name;
                var userId = item.data.user;
                jQuery.each(item.data.data, function(i, nav) {
                    var ts = nav.timestamp;
                    var lat = nav.latitude;
                    var long = nav.longitude;

                    if (lat != null && long != null) {
                        addMarker(name, counts = counts + 1, ts, lat, long, userId);
                        polyArray.push( [ lat, long]);
                    }
                    addPolyline(polyArray, get_random_color());
                });

            })
```

And this is my old version in php which i used to accomplish the above - how can i accomplish the same in my javascript?

```
<?php

                $old_lat = $old_long = "0";
                $data = array();

                foreach($history['data'] as $i => $record) {
                    $distance = distance($record['latitude'], $record['longitude'], $old_lat, $old_long, "V");

                        if($distance >= $_SESSION['same_position']) {
                        $last_i = $i;
                        $data[$i] = $record;
                           $old_lat = $record['latitude'];
                           $old_long = $record['longitude']; 
                        } else {
                        $data[$last_i]['to_timestamp'] = $record['timestamp'];
                           $old_lat = $record['latitude'];
                           $old_long = $record['longitude']; 
                        }

                }

                foreach($data as $record) {
                echo 'add(jQuery(this), number += 1, "' . $record['timestamp'] . '", "' . $name . '", "' . $history['user'] . '", "' . $record['latitude'] . '", "' . $record['longitude'] . '", "' . $record['to_timestamp'] . '");';
                }

                   ?>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Are you having a problem with the actual distance between points calculation, or just with implementing it in JavaScript?

Comment: i can calculate the difference fine with google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(). Its just making the javascript version work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see what you calculate there(where is distance()?, what doesn't work as expected? ), but it shouldn't make any difference to PHP which maps-API -version you use.

However, you may calculate the distance on clientside using the geometry-library:

[google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#spherical)